# I Transferred Over Entire WP Website to Fresh LAMP Server, PHP Not Working?

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu

I've setup a new LAMP server on Ubuntu 16.04 with Wordpress installed. On the site I have a unique algorithm that creates a new page dynamically based on a template like this:

```
http://example.com/sign-up/planid?=xxxxx
```

However when I navigate to that page, it gives me an HTTP 500 error page.

Error log gives me:

```
PHP Parse error:  Invalid numeric literal on "filename" at line 1227.
```

Comment: And what do your error logs say?

Comment: PHP Parse error:  Invalid numeric literal on line 1227

Comment: You need to show the code around that area...